# How much is Hg/Git repository corruption an issue?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

*Environment: 14 or so engineers/physicists/mathematicians (read: none really interested in spending their time on things like repo maintance and similar things)*

They will be using it, in terms of software engineering nowadays, for rather small projects, but one can expect that a lot of non-code stuff will also wind up in there (data files, some images, some PDF and word documents ... nothing large in size but it will wind up in there along with the source files).

***How much is repository corruption in such environment an issue when using either Hg or Git?***

*Platform: Windows and Mac's (mostly Windows)*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by corruption? Breaking recommended workflows/policies or technical errors within repositories?

Comment: @Oben Sonne - Or, without being unbecomingly concise, I'm worried about what can happen to a repo in general in terms of corruption? To tell the truth I don't know much about the subject, but just seeing a lot of questions on for example, StackOverflow, makes me a little worried. I personally use Hg, this seems more like a git issue that is often mentioned.

Comment: @Rook: Nice avatar :)  I don't know if it helps or not, but I always always do a *"hg verify"* before doing my *"hg push"*'es.  Also, I backup regularly entire repositories on-site, off-site, online-onsite, online-offsite, offline-onsite and offline-offsite (that's a lot of backups... +other developers also have entire 'clone' of Mercurial [but they don't do backups, I'm the one doing the backups]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally (using Mercurial) I never experienced a technically corrupted repository. Actually I'd say the chance to corrupt a repository is very very low when using the regular commands only (add/remove files, commit, push, pull, merge).

Things might get more complicated when you start playing around with history, e.g. permanently delete changesets, rebase branches, collapse changesets -- these action inherently are destructive. However, while you can act destructively in Mercurial, you'll have to enable the corresponding commands explicitly and often get meaningful warnings prior execution of potentially problematic commands.

AFAIK Git has less barriers in corrupting a repository because it supports more destructive action by default (Git users, correct me if I'm wrong).

**Finally you shouldn't care that much:** One big advantage of DVCS is that each clone is an independent complete repository. If a repo is corrupted, only one or a few developers are affected by this problem. If the problem cannot be fixed, reclone from the central or a colleague's repo and continue working on that state.

Comment: There's a difference between permanently changing things (which certain commands may do) and corrupting things, which no command should do.

Comment: Absolutely. The point is that the term *corrupt* is a bit ambiguous here. In may answer I used it as a rather subjective perception: for repository states *one dislikes or doesn't understands while one has no idea how to "fix" it to a state one prefers* -- this includes real technical errors as well as unintended results of perfectly working destructive commands.

Answer (score 3):

If by corruption you mean erroneous manipulation that will lead to a strange state of the repository, there sure will be some at the beginning when your coworkers will learn to use the new tool.

But Git and Mercurial both offer some tools to mend broken repositories. As long as your team is disciplined, I think it's safe to say that there will be no corruption problem that can't be corrected.

I advice you to choose at least one person as administrator and then take your time to think about the structure you want to give to your repositories.

Comment: Well, there is this fella who took care of our Subversion repo, I gather he will be in charge of the new main one as well. He is not a trained admin/programmer, but he can mandate some repo policies for the main line of development, as long as it doesn't inconvenience anyone too much. Hiring a new person just for that (repo management) is not even an option.

Comment: So, you think that as long as folks "don't exercise too much freedom" that no trouble can be expected? (personal opinion?)

Comment: Git and Mercurial are both robust solutions and they both offers many ways of correcting problems. Sure, someone with harm in mind could do some pretty nasty things, but as long as your coworkers take the time to learn the basics and asks question when they're not sure, I think there will be no problems.  Concerning the administrator, I wasn't suggesting hiring someone, just pick someone in your crew which will be responsible for the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about on-disk corruption. Sure, having everything tightly packed makes a bit flip more dangerous, but since everything is cloned everywhere else you're unlikely to lose data.